# Why am I getting a different response from server with URL passed from list to requests.get() vs. hard-coded string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape pre-rendered JSON from multiple URLS from a particular server.

When I use `requests.get()` with a hardcoded URL, or a string-type variable containing a hard-coded URL, I get the JSON I want from server.

```
requests.get("https://example.url/example.cgi/example")
```

the `.headers` property on the response object returns:

```
{'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Wed, 28 Oct 2020 00:49:22 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Confex-Backend': 'es-director', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

But, when I pass the exact same url from a list to `requests.get()`:

```
    url_list = ['https://example.url/example.cgi/example']    
    
    for url in url_list:
        requests.get(url)
```

I do not get the JSON response from the server. I get HTML instead with none of the JSON I want, shown here by the header to the response object (can't post the contents or the server URL here):

```
{'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Wed, 28 Oct 2020 00:49:22 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache,no-store', 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT', 'X-Confex-Backend': 'weba13', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

I'm stumped. I've tried converting the list item variable to string, re-encoding it, etc... I've even tried switching up the order of the `get` requests in my testing and I get the same results. What is going on with `requests.get()` that a URL passed as a list item to the method gets a very different response from the server than the same URL when it's hard-coded into the method, or into a variable passed to the method? What am I missing? Suffice to say, for obvious reasons it would be great to iterate `requests.get()` through a list of URLs for this particular purpose...

Comment: I agree.  This makes no sense.  You're absolutely 100% positive it's the same URL both times?  (Put `MY_URL = "https:/...../example"` at the top of your file, and use `MY_URL` instead of writing it out twice.).

Comment: Yup... I spent a solid hour making sure in my testing... even the ```.url``` property on the response object when using a list item is the exact same string as the hardcoded html is the exact same as passing the url via a variable (don't worry I'm all about defining my parameters at the top of the file... the code above is purely illustrative).

Comment: Ah you were right... it turns out the URLs were off by one character in the middle of the URL.  Explanation in answer below...

Comment: That's the reason I suggested putting the URL into a variable. . . .  It's a really good way of finding face palms.  It guarantees that things that are supposed to be the same really are.

Comment: If you read my question more carefully you may notice the "in a string-type variable" in the 2nd sentence.  Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: Sorry.  I wasn't clear.  The **same** variable in both cases.  You need to set a single variable to a value, and then use that one variable performing both test cases in the same file.  Putting the value in a variable doesn't help if they're different variables.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  -Facepalm-

So, in this particular case I had compiled the URLs in the list objects from scraping HTML on saidsame site. It turns out that those URLs are one character off from the hardcoded URLs I was seeing XHR GET requests use to get the JSON.  `app.cgi` vs `api.cgi` in the middle of the URL. Now I know to run checks on that sort of thing in the future.